# subsubsection with letter

Tags: sectioning, letters

So, I am writing a RMD file and and I want my subsubsections to be fronted by letters and not numerics. I can do this by hand but I want to use `number_sections: true` for conviniance. Hence, I tried rewritting the subsubsection command with:

```
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\Alph{subsubsection}}
```

I imported the rewritten funciton it in my RMD file. However, this is without success. What am I doing wrong do I need to specify further arguments in my function?

Any help is warmly welcome!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! This may depend on the document class, on packages you load. Please post a minimal example illustrating the problem

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\Alph{subsubsection}}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schrödinger's cat's
 `\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\Alph{subsubsection}}`
did the trick for me.